# submit javascript form using python and requests

Tags: javascript, python, forms

I'm trying to automate submitting a javascript form using Python and the Requests module. I used Chrome's developer tools to inspect the request being sent if I do it via the browser - I tried to mimic the data dictionary when submitting via Python's requests library. I'm receiving the 200 code when I check r.status_code but when I go to test submitting again (it's supposed to tell you that only one submission can be made per 24 hours) it works... So I'm guessing my post request isn't going through properly. This is the website I'm trying to submit to: http://mybobs.pgtb.me/wb7VQD/

This is what I have included in my code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://mybobs.pgtb.me/wb7VQD/jcb3H?w=37627165&e=98541503'


payload = {
    'promotion[first_name]': 'Jack',
    'promotion[last_name]': 'Daniel',
    'promotion[email]': 'testtestyy@gmail.com',
    'promotion[city]': 'Chicago',
    'promotion[province]': '06096',
    'promotion[postal_code]': 'IL',
    'promotion[custom_field_1]': '1',
    'promotion[agree]': '1'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple... I've never interacted with web pages using Python before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a user of python, but your requests are going directly to the server. There is no browser, and if you're not storing cookies / session data, the server may not know that you have already submitted a request. Are you committed to using python for this?

Comment: real POST request more complex then yours. Fastest way - submit this form with selenium webdriver. BTW, looks like url is your referral link

Comment: @ElRuso I looked at the contents of the request using Chrome, I don't really understand what should be included in the request. According to Chrome, there are pretty lengthy request headers. What I put in the 'payload' was under "form data" - I'm guessing that's not enough? Thanks!

Comment: As I say, simplest and fastest way - use selenium and real browser. All cookies and POST data will be set correctly